# Rounding numbers to the same distance

Tags: javascript

Is there are a way to round different values so it have the same "distance"? For example I have this values:

```
100
105.3
110.7
115.1
```

When I would use Math.round() the distance between the numbers are different:

```
100
105 // distance is 5 to the previous value
111 // distance is 6 to the previous value 
115 // distance is 4 to the previous value
```

Of course I could use Math.floor() or Math.ceil() but the problem is that the values will be different at runtime and the distance will be never the same for all the numbers.

I need this for SVG objects:

```
line.setAttribute('x1', Math.round(x1)); // x1 will have values like 85, 130.3, 175.6, 220.89999999999998 for example
```

Comment: Round `100` and `115.1` then generate 2 values inbetween.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider that "rounding" as much as you're interested in a variance. The problem is, I'm not sure how you want this to work: should each value not be allowed to be greater than an absolute distance from the previous?

Comment: This requires a custom algorithm. How do you determine the distance?

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information. Are your numbers always in nondescending order? What is your expected output for that set of numbers?

Comment: The distance should be any of the distance values, but it should be the same. I have values like 85, 130.3, 175.6, 220.89999999999998 or 85, 116.02083333333334, 147.04166666666669, 178.0625 and want to round it so the values has the same distance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're solely considering previous values, I'd define a curried function to use for the distances you're interested in.

Below is a demo using a distance of `5`. Using `map`, you can run this on an array of data to force each entry to a defined distance from the previous.

---

**Edit**

Added `Math.round()` to the function, although you could use that outside the function on its returned value as well.

```js
const previousDistance = (distance) => (previous, current) => {
  if (current > previous) {
    return Math.round((current - previous > distance) ? previous + distance : current);
  } else {
    return Math.round((previous - current > distance) ? previous - distance : current);
  }
}

const previousDistanceFive = previousDistance(5);

// outside distance (below)
console.log(previousDistanceFive(5, -1)); // -> 0

// inside distance (below)
console.log(previousDistanceFive(5, 1.1)); // -> 1

// equal
console.log(previousDistanceFive(5, 5)); // -> 5

// inside distance (above)
console.log(previousDistanceFive(5, 9.123)); // -> 9

// outside distance (above)
console.log(previousDistanceFive(5, 11)); // - > 10


// --- DEMONSTRATION ON Array

const arr = [0, 5, 7, 16, 17, 10, 16]; // -> [0, 5, 7, 12, 17, 12, 15]

const roundedArr = arr.map((elem, i) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    return previousDistanceFive(arr[i - 1], elem);
  } else {
    return elem;
  }
});
console.log("Array Demo: ", roundedArr);
```

Comment: Thank you. I use the rounding for SVG lines like this: line.setAttribute('x1', Math.round(x1)); where x1 will be the values like 85, 130.3, 175.6, 220.89999999999998, ect. I try your function but it does not work correct (it does not round the numbers to integers). I use it this way line.setAttribute('x1', previousDistanceFive(x1, 5));

Comment: @JCss see the edit - I added `Math.round()`. Based off of what you're describing, that should work. If not, then I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I become this result: 80, 125, 171, 216 which is not equal to each other.